# Meteor app Development

Tags: meteor, nitrous

When I use  tag on my .html page to reduce my code visibility in Meteor app development. Instead of showing data of that correspondent template, it shows the name of the template..

For eg:

```
{{>season}}
  <template name="season">
    <ul><li>Summer</li></ul>
  </template>
```

.. But unfortunately in output window it appears as {{> season}}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not startup your project.

You need to do this in console:

```
cd yourappname
meteor
```

I suggest you follow this tutorial to know how to startup your project:
https://www.meteor.com/try